# How much more efficient is batch writing to a file vs individual writes?

Tags: storage, batch-processing, processing-efficiency, energy

I am trying to maximize the energy efficiency of an application and I am curious if it makes sense to queue individual write requests (to a flat file DB) such that they can be batched into a single write.

I am assuming flat file DB and am curious if the additional overhead of maintaining a queue would negate the energy savings of the batch writing.